# How do a dragDrop() with the right mouse button?

Tags: sikuli

Does anyone know how to do a `dragDrop()` with the right mouse button? 
I got this example code:

```
image = ("image.png")
App.focus('<nameProgramHere>')
imageE = find(image)
rightClick(dragDrop(imageE, imageE.offset(Location(0, -250))))
```

It does make a rightclick, but the `dragDrop()` is preformed with the left mouse click. 
(I can see this becasue the colour is then different in my program.)

I do see the rightClick() in my log. 
`[log] RIGHT CLICK on L(1039,556)@S(0)[0,0 1920x1080]`

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself on how to drag and drop with the right mouse button.

```
image = ("image.png")

imageE = find(image)
imageE.hover()
wait(2)
mouseDown(Button.RIGHT)
mouseMove(imageE.offset(Location(0,-250)))
wait(2)
mouseUp()
```